# I cannot assign a value to a variable after call a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, global-variables

I am making a modification of the popular game rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock based on a algorithm proposed by someone on this site.
Here is my Js:

```
//¿Es obligatorio declarar las variables?
var Elementos = ["AIRE", "OSCURIDAD", "AGUA", "FUEGO", "TIERRA"];
var resultados = [" empata con ", " derrota a ", " pierde con "];
var opcionUsuario = false;
var opcionMago = false;
console.log("Default " + opcionUsuario);

//¿Qué elemento eligió el usuario?
function elementoElegido(elemento){
    opcionUsuario = elemento;
    log.value = "Has elegido " + Elementos[opcionUsuario] + ".";    
    console.log("User picks " + opcionUsuario);
}

//¡A pelear!
function guerra(opcionUsuario){ 
    //console.log(opcionUsuario);

    if(opcionUsuario === false){
        log.value = "Por favor, elige un elemento primero joven aventurero."
    }else{
        opcionMago = Math.floor( Math.random() * (4 - 0 + 1) + 0 ); 
        combate(opcionUsuario, opcionMago);
    }

}

function combate(opcionUsuario, opcionMago) {         
      dif = opcionMago - opcionUsuario;
      if(dif < 0) {
          dif += Elementos.length;
      }
      while(dif > 2) {
          dif -= 2;
      }
      log.value = "Tu elección: " + Elementos[opcionUsuario] + resultados[dif] + "la elección del mago: " + Elementos[opcionMago] + ".";    

      //¡Vuelve a elegir!
      opcionUsuario = false;
      console.log(opcionUsuario);      
};
```

I set the variable opcionUsuario on false, but when I run the function guerra again, the variable opcion Usuario comes with the last value settled by the function elementoElegido. 
How can I set the variable on false again in order to force the user to choose one element before continue? Why this happens? Thanks in advance.

Here is a [live example](http://benvoide.esy.es/jz/guerradeelementos/index.html).

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `opcionUsuario = false;`?

Comment: Since you're passing it as a parameter, it is implicitly scoped to the function. Since you're declaring the variable globally, you could just not pass it as a parameter at all and it will work.

Comment: `opcionUsuario` in your functions refers to a local variable, (which has been declared within arguments), not to the global `opcionUsuario`.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan
When you set a variable outside a function, it is implictly declared as global variable?

Comment: @benvoide Not necessarily... technically, it's the variable's scope. In this instance, since you've declared the variable in the same scope as the functions it is accessible by all of them (you're utilizing this in the `elementoElegido` function).

Comment: @JesseKernaghan Excellent. I made your suggested changes and now it is working. Thanks a lot. 
How can I set the answer as resolved or something like that :P?

Comment: @benvoide added answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a value as a function parameter, it generates a local variable with the assigned value being passed so this:

```
function foo(bar){
  console.log(bar);
}

foo('hello world');
```

is actually interpreted as this:

```
function foo(bar){
   var bar = [bars value]; //in this case, 'hello world'
   console.log(bar); //logging the local variable
}

foo('hello world');
```

In order to achieve what you desire, you need reference the variable declared in the outer scope, which can be done easily:

```
var bar = 'hello world';

function foo(){
   console.log(bar);

   bar = 'goodbye world';
}

foo();//logs hello world
foo();//logs goodbye world;
console.log(bar); //goodbye world
```

Note: access to shared variables should be as limited as possible in order to reduce unexpected results and conflicts. It might be worth your time to looking into architectures that achieve this, such as the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html).